How to config router in Reactjs with NGINX?
I want to run a Reactjs application with Nginx, I want to run it with location /admin
This is the router configuration in my Reactjs application
const RouterConfig = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/public" component={(props: any) => <UserLayout {...props} />} />
        <ProtectedRoute path="/">
          <AppLayout />
        </ProtectedRoute>
        <ProtectedRoute path="/admin">
          <AppLayout />
        </ProtectedRoute>
        <ProtectedRoute path={['/dashboard', '/support', '/settings']}>
          <DashBoardLayout />
        </ProtectedRoute>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <AppLayout />
        </Route>
    </Switch>
  );
};

I run Reactjs application with pm2 on port 3000 and here is my Nginx config
 location ^~ /admin {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;        
        rewrite ^/admin(/.*)$ $1 break;
 }

but when I access

server_name/admin

I get a white screen, maybe the router is wrong but I don't know how to fix it
Can you guys tell me how to fix it?

If I am not wrong then you want to serve your React's root (index.html) from the /admin location instead of the default /.
